# How to test paired sequences

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

I have a `template` sequence is about a standard product before the test:

> template = {78, 81, 69, 69, 58, 52, 84}

Each element in the sequence is an attribute of the standard product, and the values of these attributes are arranged in strict order. The absolute magnitude of the property values may shift each time they are tested, but if the product is normal, their relative magnitude should be essentially the same as that of the standard sample. Then I detect the samples one by one, then I get `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`

```
a = {123, 107, 107, 107, 112, 84, 131}
b = {124, 114, 108, 106, 106, 79, 121}
c = {126, 122, 106, 116, 115, 86, 138}
d = {125, 111, 179, 115, 115, 88, 125}
e = {123, 107, 178, 108, 107, 85, 124}
```

[image]

As you see, the `a`,`b` and `c` are pairable sequences with the `template`(The trends look similar), because they are normal product. But `d` and `e` are not(They look like they have outliers). I don't know what statistics method can help me pick out these normal products. I use the function `FisherRatioTest` in [Wolfram Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) to test them and I get a good result:

```
a:0.609172
b:0.613782
c:0.453069
d:0.0582011
e:0.046925
```

There is a very large difference between the scores for (`a`, `b`, `c`) VS (`d` , `e`), which is obviously a very **good result**. However, there are two problems if I use `FisherRatioTest`(f-test) here:

1. `FisherRatioTest` requires the test data to be normally distributed, but my sequence doesn't satisfy a particular distribution.
2. `FisherRatioTest` does not care about the order of elements in a sequence.

So I would like to ask if there is a more suitable test pairable sequences in statistics for this purpose.

Comment: The Fisher ratio test is a comparison of variances, not of identical distributions.   Your $d$ and $e$ sequences have the $179$ and $178$ values much higher than the other terms, which push up their variances substantially

Comment: @Henry You've upgraded my question based on your hints, and this might be a better way to phrase it

Comment: Although I appreciate that you offer examples, which is a technique that usually works well, I still have no definite sense of what "pairable ... with the template" or "this relationship" are intended to mean.  Could you please explain?  What do the template and the sequences represent?  How were they obtained?  Are any of them data?  Which?

Comment: @whuber I have refined my post in response to your doubt